# Using a Friend Operator Assignment and private variable is inaccessible

Tags: c++

I am attempting to get the "sum += A" to work in my code I am learning about writing operators but mainly dealt with objects on the left side so because of the sum being a double type I am  unsure on how to code my operator to add the value of sum with the balance variable in the bank object and return the sum in the operator.

In my main I have

```
double sum = 0;
Bank A("Tom", 500.50);
Bank B("Sam", 123.45);
sum += A;
sum += B;
cout << sum << endl;
```

In my header and implementation file I have

```
 class Bank{
    char name[31];
    double balance;
  public:
    friend double operator+=(double, const Bank&);
};

double operator+=(double a, Bank& rhs) {
  a += rhs.balance;
return a;
}
```

I have tried using it without a friend but I am unsure of the correct syntax for having a double value when working with assignment operators. Any help would be appreaicated.

Comment: What are your problems? If you get build errors please include them (in full, and unedited). If you get unexpected results please show input, actual output and expected output. And please edit your question to include that information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a couple of problems.

First - your `friend` declaration and your method definition don't match (you missed out a `const`). This means that the method definition is not a friend.

Second - the `+=` operator needs to take its first parameter as a reference, so it can update it. It should also return a reference.

So you should end up with

```
    ...
    friend double & operator+=(double &, const Bank&);
};

double & operator+=(double &a, const Bank& rhs) {
    a += rhs.balance;
    return a;
}
```

Comment: My code worked without the & between double and operator if you don't mind can you explain on what that adds to the program?

Comment: It would only be used if you used the return value, something like `sum2 = sum += A`, or possibly `cout << (sum += A)`, or even `(sum += A)++`. Note that none of those are very readable, so I wouldn't recommend it. It needs to be a reference so that the last example can update the value, rather than updating a copy.

Answer (score 0):

In your implementation of `operator+=`, you are changing a local copy of the variable. It doesn't change the variable in the calling function. You need to use:

```
double& operator+=(double& a, const Bank& rhs) {
   a += rhs.balance;
   return a;
}
```

Also, you need to provide a constructor in `Bank` to be able to construct instances of the class, something like:

```
Bank(char const* n, double b) : balance(b)
{
   std::strcpy(name, n);
}
```